# How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server with condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
Id   GroupId  StdId  Active
---------------------------
1    1        1      true
2    1        2      false
3    1        1      false
4    1        1      false
5    1        1      true
6    1        2      true
```

I want to delete duplicate row but if Active have true/false value keep true value and delete false value.

For example I want to this list

```
Id   GroupId  StdId  Active
---------------------------
1    1        1      true
6    1        2      true
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if all the active flags fro a given set are false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
  SELECT Id, GroupId, StdId, Active,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId, StdId
                            ORDER BY Active Desc, Id) AS rn
  FROM mytable 
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE (rn > 1) OR (rn =1 AND Active = 0)
```

The above assumes that `Active` is actually a `bit` field.

`ROW_NUMBER` helps us identify duplicate records. Those with `Active=1` will take precedence over those with `Active=0` within each `GroupId, StdId` partition. Using a `CTE` we can easily delete all duplicate rows filtering out the top level record, in case it is an `Active=1` one.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39b53/1)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I know, that's why I added with an edit the `(rn =1 AND Active = 0)` predicate. The OP can leave this out if he wants to *always* leave one record. But I think this is not what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to keep one row per `StdId`, with a preference for true rows.  If so:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by groupid order by active desc, id desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1;
```

This keeps exactly one record per `stdId`, with preference for keeping an active one.  If all the records are false, then it keeps the false one with the largest id.